# How do I add binary media types to an existing API Gateway that I've imported into a CDK stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an AWS CDK stack in which I'm referencing an existing API Gateway like this:

```
api = apigateway.RestApi.from_rest_api_attributes(self, "API", 
    rest_api_id="api-id", root_resource_id="root-resource-id")
```

After I have the reference, I want to configure the allowed binary media types to be "application/pdf" and "image/*". The problem is that I can't find a method where I can set these. The only place I've found where you can set the binary media types is in the [constructor for the RestApi class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/RestApi.html) and I can't use that because the API has already been created.

There is a `binary_media_types` property on the `RestApi` class, but that had no effect when I tried setting its value:

```
api.binary_media_types = ["application/pdf", "image/*"]
```

Does anyone know another way to change the binary media types in this situation by using the CDK library?

Comment: Is the API Gateway also created in CDK? If not CDK, what is the mechanism used to create it?

Comment: The API is created by a Service Catalog product.